# Map editor and wrong item spawns problem in Unturned

Tags: unturned

I was creating my own map for Unturned, and I come across problems with item spawns.
I created for now three tables named: GunBox, Flashlight, cloths.

I have experienced problem with `cloths`. This is list of ID's which are inside:
`313, 433, 430, 9, 159, 2, 1014, 165, 208, 200, 1011, 1012, 185, 1156, 1157, 156, 1199`. Everything adds nicely, I have separated those items to four tiers, and everything seems to be fine. The item names next to id's after adding them, are only cloths.

The problem comes when I am turning on the map. Instead of cloths I am getting `raw salmon` which I checked and have id `505` which is not on the list. The game spawned also few other items in this place, however none of it was any of item on the list.

I had also made sure that ID's inside list are right - I even used `give` command to check each item IS, and none of them is wrong.

**Is there any way to fix it?**

**Edit**: I forget to mention that I am running version 3.15.0.2, and already verified all files few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue, but I think it has something to do with the "Arena Spawn Tables" that Unturned gives us. When I type in the ID 6, it shows up as a Military Magazine, but when I play the game, a variety of guns come out from the "6 Arena_Guns_Military_Rare - Tables". In your case, "313, 433, 430, 9, 159, 2, 1014, 165, 208, 200, 1011, 1012, 185, 1156, 1157, 156, 1199" would mix most of the numbers up and change it into "raw salmon". Although I am having the same problem, that is what I believe. I do not think it is correct, but I am the first person to probably debunk this. I am running Unturned version ~ 3.15.11.0

Have a good day! - 8/3/2016

Comment: It seems actually only reasonable reason and since I asked this question I didn't really found an fix, I will accept it anyway